PowerBI/Power Query - Convert Unix Time to PQ DateTime
Using PowerBI, I want to convert whole number values (eg. 1665158288, 1665159555, etc) to datetime.
I have tried the following approach the date_output is whole number formatted, but encounter errors.

date_output = DateTime.From([upLoad_date] * 86400)

Each cell has errors such as below. 

DataFormat.Error: We couldn't convert to DateTime.
Details:
1.4387E+14


What do the numbers represent? Unix time?

Hi, yes they are unix time values.

try Date.Add(DateTime.From(1970, 1, 1), #duration(0, 0, 0, [upLoad_date]))

It errors... "Expression.Error: The name 'Date.Add' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's spelled correctly."

yeah. sorry it should be #datetime(1970,1,1) + #duration(0, 0, 0, [upLoad_date])

#datetime(1970,1,1,0,0,0)+ #duration(0,0,0,[Unix])



